# Can a chaincode interact with other chaincode?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to write an application with hyper-ledger and I was looking for a way to communicate with chain-code from another chain-code. Is that possible in hyper-ledger?

I know its possible in etherum to communicate with other smart contracts but is the same possible in hyperledger. I could not find any related links related to same. Any suggestions on how to approach this will be really helpful.

I checked out [Writing Your First Application](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html), but I could not find the suitable explanation for same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chaincode could interact with other chaincode by means of leveraging existing [API](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L80) of `ChaincodeStubInterface`, e.g.:

```
// InvokeChaincode locally calls the specified chaincode `Invoke` using the
// same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't
// create a new transaction message.
// If the called chaincode is on the same channel, it simply adds the called
// chaincode read set and write set to the calling transaction.
// If the called chaincode is on a different channel,
// only the Response is returned to the calling chaincode; any PutState calls
// from the called chaincode will not have any effect on the ledger; that is,
// the called chaincode on a different channel will not have its read set
// and write set applied to the transaction. Only the calling chaincode's
// read set and write set will be applied to the transaction. Effectively
// the called chaincode on a different channel is a `Query`, which does not
// participate in state validation checks in subsequent commit phase.
// If `channel` is empty, the caller's channel is assumed.
InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName string, args [][]byte, channel string) pb.Response
```

Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
response := stub.InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName, chainCodeArgs, channelName)
```

Of course peer should have rights and chaincode installed.

Comment: API link is broken. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @WebArtisan I've traced the repo. The link directed you to `interface.go`
So, I think it should be this file https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go.

Comment: In chaincode to chaincode call, what happens if current chaincode calls private data transaction of another chaincode in "same channel"? Currently, HLF version is 1.4.4